# QT6 Android app: mapping a QVideoFrame from QVideoSink after app in background crashes with OpenGL ES API no current context

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I do have a Qt6 (6.5.0) Quick Android application. The application uses the Qt `Camera` and shows the stream to the `VideoOutput` element that fills the screen.
When the `Take frame` button is pressed, the `backend` method `setVideoSink` is called. There I get a `QVideoFrame` from the `QVideoSink`, make a non-const copy, map it (call method `map`), do some work (or nothing in the case), and unmap (call method 'unmap`).

Everything fine until the app goes to background and is restored (resumed): when the `map` method is called on the copy frame, the application crashes, with the log:

```
E libEGL  : call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so: Failed to compile shader:
W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so: Source was:
W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so: #version 100
06-16 13:32:36.205 18373 18394 W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so:
W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so: struct buf
W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so: {
W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so:     mat4 matrix;
W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so:     mat4 colorMatrix;
W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so:     float opacity;
W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so:     float width;
W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so:     float masteringWhite;
W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so:     float maxLum;
W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so: };
06-16 13:32:36.205 18373 18394 W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so:
W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so: uniform buf ubuf;
06-16 13:32:36.205 18373 18394 W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so:
W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so: varying vec2 texCoord;
W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so: attribute vec2 vertexTexCoord;
W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so: attribute vec4 vertexPosition;
06-16 13:32:36.205 18373 18394 W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so:
W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so: void main()
W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so: {
W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so:     texCoord = vertexTexCoord;
W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so:     gl_Position = ubuf.matrix * vertexPosition;
W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so: }
06-16 13:32:36.205 18373 18394 W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so:
06-16 13:32:36.205 18373 18394 W libappCameraProcessor_arm64-v8a.so:
W CameraProcesso: 0xebadde09 skipped times: 0
F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x78 in tid 18394 (qtMainLoopThrea), pid 18373 (CameraProcessor)
```

Now, the source code of the application:

Main.qml

```
import QtQuick.Window
import QtMultimedia
import QtQuick.Controls

import Backend

Window {
    width: 1920
    height: 1024
    visible: true

    Camera {
       id: userCamera
       focusMode: Camera.FocusModeAuto
    }

    CaptureSession {
       id: viewFinderCaptureSession
       videoOutput: viewfinder
       camera: userCamera
    }

    VideoOutput {
        id: viewfinder
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Backend{
        id: backend
        objectName: "backend"
    }

    Component.onCompleted: userCamera.start()

    Button {
        id: processButton
        onClicked: backend.videSink = viewfinder.videoSink

        width: 200
        height: 50
        text: "Take frame"

        x: 20
        y: 20
    }

}
```

backend.h

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QVideoSink>
#include <QVideoFrame>
#include <QVariant>

class backend : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    backend(QObject* _parent = nullptr);

    Q_INVOKABLE void setVideoSink(QVideoSink* _videoSink);
    void disconnectSink();
};
```

backend.cpp

```
#include "backend.h"

#include <QDebug>

backend::backend(QObject* _parent):
    QObject(_parent)
{
    // noting to do...
}


void backend::setVideoSink(QVideoSink* _videoSink)
{
    auto myFrame = _videoSink->videoFrame();
    qDebug() << "map frame; is valid: " << myFrame.isValid() << "isMapped: " << myFrame.isMapped();
    myFrame.map(QVideoFrame::MapMode::ReadOnly);
    // TODO here comes some work ...
    myFrame.unmap();
}
```

The Backend is a C++ class registered in the 'main()' function.

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include "backend.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qmlRegisterType< backend >( "Backend", 1, 0, "Backend" );

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
        &app, []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);

    engine.loadFromModule("CameraProcessor", "Main");

    QObject::connect(&app, &QGuiApplication::applicationStateChanged, [](Qt::ApplicationState _state){
        qDebug() << "State changed to: " << _state;
    });

    return app.exec();
}
```

What is the problem here? Any idea to fix it?
Examples or suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it has a solution only by fixing qt code. it's a big bug connected with qtmultimedia/qtgui. even for workaround you need to recompile qt

Comment: probably you can find working qt version before this merge https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtmultimedia/+/434075?tab=comments

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-113616